# How can i prove this inequaty right? $2^{n+2}+1- \sum_{k=0}^{2n} 1.4^k > 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

When I look at the graph of this function I am sure it has to be true, but I can't find a way to show it with good old arithmetics.

Here's the inequaty:

$2^{n+2}+1-$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n} 1.4^k > 0$

Comment: What's the comma doing between 1 and 4?

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife Ohhh sorry... I am from Germany... Gonna change it into a dot. Thanks.

Comment: Your sum is a finite [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife So would it be (1-1,4^2n+1)/(1-1,4)?

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife Okay thank you a lot. Sorry that I didn't know about these ones :/

Answer (score 0):

By the formula
for the sum of a
geometric series,
$\sum_{k=0}^{2n} c^k
=\dfrac{c^{2n+1}-1}{c-1}
$.

Since $1.4 < \sqrt{2}$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{2n} 1.4^k
&=\dfrac{1.4^{2n+1}-1}{1.4-1}\\
&=\dfrac{1.4((1.4)^2)^n-1}{.4}\\
&=2.5(1.4((1.4)^2)^n-1)\\
&<2.5(1.4(2)^n-1)\\
&<3.5\cdot 2^n-2.5\\
&<4\cdot 2^n-1\\
&= 2^{n+2}-1\\
\end{array}
$